# Plotting multiple line graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I am trying to create a plot in R that shows post-surgical outcomes over time. Each row in the dataframe has up to 8 measurements at different time points post-surgery (with some missing values), and for each row, I want to create a line graph that shows the change in the measurement over time. Here is an example dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(Preop=c(-2,0.5,-0.25,1.5), PO_1M=c(-1.5,0.2,-0.1,1.0), PO_6M=c(-1.2,0.1,-0.05,0.5), PO_1Y=c(-1.0,0.05,0,0.25))
dat
```

I have tried the following code to rearrange the data and get a plot with points over time, but I want to change this so that each row is maintained and can create a line graph.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2<-dat %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=Preop:PO_1Y)

dat2$nummonths<-ifelse(dat2$name=='Preop',0,
             ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_1M',1,
                    ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_6M',6,
                                  ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_1Y',12,NA))))

ggplot(dat2, aes(nummonths,value))+geom_point()
```

I want the graph to look something like this:
[image]

Currently, I have the points plotted, but I do not know how to connect these points to create a line graph. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need an `id` of sorts in the data in order to group by it and plot it accordingly. Here's a dplyr suggestion to get you started:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
  mutate(id = factor(row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=Preop:PO_1Y) %>%
  mutate(NumMonths = case_when(name == "Preop" ~ 0, name == "PO_1M" ~ 1, name == "PO_6M" ~ 6, name == "PO_1Y" ~ 12, TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(NumMonths, value)) + geom_path(aes(group = id, color = id))
```

[image: sample ggplot2]

An alternative (in place of `case_when`) is to define a lookup table of `Months` that maps names to number of months, and then you can easily use this to add some context to your plot:

```r
Months <- tibble(
  name = c("Preop", "PO_1M", "PO_6M", "PO_1Y"),
  NumMonths = c(0, 1, 6, 12)
)
dat %>%
  mutate(id = factor(row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=Preop:PO_1Y) %>%
  left_join(., Months, by = "name") %>%
  ggplot(aes(NumMonths, value)) +
    geom_text(aes(y = -Inf, label = name), data = Months, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, angle = 90) +
    geom_path(aes(group = id, color = id)) +
    geom_point(aes(group = id, color = id))
```

[image: improved ggplot2]

While it can arguably be improved aesthetically, I think the structure of it should be clear enough.